# Queries about how this hall sensor is connected to the MCU

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, stm32, hall-effect

This is part of the schematics from the [STSPIN32F0251 EVB](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00642656-evspin32f0251s1-3phase-inverter-based-on-stspin32f0251-stmicroelectronics.pdf) that shows how the hall sensors are connected to the MCU. What purpose do the `10pF` capacitors and the `BAT54J` diodes serve? Do the capacitors and the `10K` pull-up resistors form an RC network of some kind? Also, are the `1.8K` resistors for current limiting?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diodes are a clamp to ensure the inputs to the micro don't exceed Vdd by any great margin.

The 10k/10pF have a time constant around 100ns. So it might be a glitch filter or a ESD/EMI filter

The 1k8 are for input current limiting.

Basically some input protection as the wiring from the hall sensors will act as antennas and pick up noise.